# Why C++17 class template argument deduction fails?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, class-template

C++17 offers [class template argument deduction](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

I have the following small example (you can paste into onlinegdb with C++17 enabled, no problem) where it fails under certain circumstances but I do not know why:

```
#include <iostream>
enum class Res{
    ResA,
    ResB
};

template<Res>
class B{   
};

template<Res T>
class A{
    //If I remove this construtor, template type deduction will not work anymore
    public:   
    A(B<T> b){       
    }
};

template<>
class A<Res::ResA>{
    public:
    A(B<Res::ResA> b){
        std::cout<<"A res A\n";
    }  
};

int main()
{
    B<Res::ResA> b;
    A a(b);
}
```

The code above works. But as soon as I change `A`'s constructor to be the any other constructor than in the template specializations, the template argument deduction will not work and `A` has to be initialized by `A<Res::ResA>`.

I am at loss. Why could this be the case? Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I guess the compiler ignores the specializations for argument deduction. So there's no way it would know what T should be.

Comment: FWIW, to keep yourself sane, when you have a template specialization, pretend that it doesn't exist.  They don't actually come into play until the primary template is resolved and are only used with the primary template matches the template specialization.  Until then, all it is is just a recipe for those particular template parameters.

Comment: Elliot, what difference does this make semantically?

Comment: @Elliott There is no deduction in that case, there is only a default value for the template parameter so it would only make the code work for that specific specialization. That doesn't really answer the question or solve any issues with CTAD. It only makes this specific snippet of code compile.

Comment: @Elliott No, the compiler doesn't deduce anything. You are telling it explicitly that the template parameter should be `Res::ResA` if it's not deducable. If you would add another template specialization `A<Res::ResB>` that takes an `B<Res::ResB>` in it's constructor it wouldn't work since there is not actual deduction involved. Only a default value.

Comment: @Elliott I think you are missing the point. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/4o4r4K) is what I mean. My point is that a question like this is not about "how can I make this specific snippet compile" it's about *why* it doesn't work in the first place and *how* the actual mechanic of CTAD works.

Comment: @Elliott What part of it? You said `The argument deduction works at the base class`. I said there is no deduction. My link clearly shows that there is no deduction.

Comment: @Elliott Additionally you said `This approach can be used if you have many different specialisations.` which again, my code clearly shows it can not.

Comment: @Elliott `A<Res::ResB>` has a constructor that takes a `B<Res::ResB>` which is what I'm giving it. And it fails to deduce the right specialization since there is no deduction.

Comment: @Elliott Yes, but that is not deduction. That is equivalent to explicitly specifying the template argument and as such has nothing to do with CTAD which is what the question asks about. Additionally it is *not* an approach that can be used if you have many different specialization since you can only give the primary template one default.

Answer (score 4):

Generated [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) are only from **primary** template.

If you don't want to add that constructor in primary template, you can still provide custom deduction guide.